# Why won't my drupal module show up in the modules list?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

My drupal module won't show up for me. My code is:

**.project**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>db_connection</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

**db_select_module.info**

```
name=DB balance
description= a test module to practice database selecting.
core= 7.x
```

**db_select_module_balance.module**

```
    function dp_select_module_block_info() {
      $blocks['dp_select_module'] = array(
        'info' => t('DataBase Calls'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,

  );
  return $blocks;
}
/**
 * 
 * Function to get data from database.
 */
function dp_select_module_get_data() {
  $query= db_select('balancetable', 'c')
    ->fields('c', array('name','username','balance'))
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
  return $query;    
}

/**
 * Implemented block view.
 */
function dp_select_module_block_view1() {
  $result= dp_select_module_get_data();
  //$items= array();
  $output= '<ul>';
  foreach($result as $key){
 $output.= '<li>' .$key->name. '</li>';
 $ output.= '<li>' .$key->username. '</li>';
 $output.= '<li>' .$key->balance. '</li>';  
  }
  $output.= '</ul>';
  $block['content'] = $output;
  return $block;
}
```

My database table details:

> Table Name:  balancetable
>
> Columns:
>
> id | name | username | balance

So is there something I'm doing wrong in the code? Shouldn't the module still show up but just say there are errors? I did modify a pre-existing module and changed the name etc so could that be why I'm getting this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming `db_select_module_balance.module` to `db_select_module.module` to match your .info file.

Also checking these files are in

```
/sites/all/modules/db_select_module/
```

Comment: hello, thanks. I've tried this an still getting the same issue. Would I need to rename anything inside the module file as well? Could the other module with the same functions cause the issue?

Comment: have you cleared your drupal caches? Also it appears the functions in the .module file start with `dp_` instead of the `db_` in the filenames.